# Table with sticky heading and rounded corners in TailwindCSS

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have troubles getting a Table with sticky heading and rounded corners in TailwindCSS.

I have the sticky heading but once I hide the overflow for the corners, sticky heading doesn't work anymore and vice-versa.

Keeping `overflow-x-auto` and `overflow-hidden` keeps the rounded corners but removes the sticky positioning:

https://play.tailwindcss.com/VsjHVVmKQr

Removing `overflow-x-auto` and `overflow-hidden` keeps sticky positioning but removes the rounded corners:

https://play.tailwindcss.com/SDqMXQ3f0a

```html
<div class="px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
    <div class="mt-8 flex flex-col">
        <div class="-my-2 -mx-4 overflow-x-auto sm:-mx-6 lg:-mx-8">
            <div class="inline-block min-w-full py-2 align-middle md:px-6 lg:px-8">
                <div class="overflow-hidden shadow ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 md:rounded-lg">
                    <table class="min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-300">
                        <thead class="bg-indigo-500 sticky top-0">
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col" class="py-3.5 pl-4 pr-3 text-left text-sm font-semibold text-white sm:pl-6">First name</th>
                            <th scope="col" class="px-3 py-3.5 text-left text-sm font-semibold text-white">Last name</th>
                            <th scope="col" class="px-3 py-3.5 text-left text-sm font-semibold text-white">Email</th>
                            <th scope="col" class="relative py-3.5 pl-3 pr-4 sm:pr-6">
                                <span class="sr-only">Edit</span>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody class="divide-y divide-indigo-200 bg-white">
                       
                        <!-- More rows... -->
                        
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I get both, a sticky header with rounded corners?

Answer (score 0):

Even if I'd prefer a native `TailwindCSS` solution, I build one with `AlpineJS`.

The concept is based on the scroll behavior. If the user scrolls down to the upper-line of the table heading, appropriated classes will be hidden and/or shown.

I'm using `@scroll.window="stick = (window.pageYOffset > 31) ? true : false"` to measure the scroll page Y offset and set the `stick` variable to `true` or `false`. In this particular case, the offset will be 31px.

Based on the the `stick` state, I modify the classes where needed.

Check-out the code and demo right here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Tailwind Demo</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <script defer src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>
<body class="bg-indigo-200">
<div class="px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
    <div class="mt-8 flex flex-col">
        <div
            x-data="{ stick: false}"
            @scroll.window="stick = (window.pageYOffset > 31) ? true : false"
            :class="{'overflow-x-auto': stick === false}"
            class="-my-2 -mx-4 overflow-x-auto sm:-mx-6 lg:-mx-8"
        >
            <div class="inline-block min-w-full py-2 align-middle md:px-6 lg:px-8">
                <div
                    class="shadow ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 md:rounded-lg"
                    :class="{'overflow-hidden': stick === false}"
                >
                    <table class="min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-300">
                        <thead
                            class="bg-indigo-500"
                            :class="{'sticky top-0': stick === true}"
                        >
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col" class="py-3.5 pl-4 pr-3 text-left text-sm font-semibold text-white sm:pl-6">First name</th>
                            <th scope="col" class="px-3 py-3.5 text-left text-sm font-semibold text-white">Last name</th>
                            <th scope="col" class="px-3 py-3.5 text-left text-sm font-semibold text-white">Email</th>
                            <th scope="col" class="relative py-3.5 pl-3 pr-4 sm:pr-6">
                                <span class="sr-only">Edit</span>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody class="divide-y divide-indigo-200 bg-white">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 py-4 pl-4 pr-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 sm:pl-6">Golden</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">Funk</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">georgiana.walter@example.net</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 py-4 pl-3 pr-4 text-right text-sm font-medium sm:pr-6">
                                <a href="#" class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900">Edit<span class="sr-only">, Lindsay Walton</span></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 py-4 pl-4 pr-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 sm:pl-6">Cornell</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">Quitzon</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">mae26@example.com</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 py-4 pl-3 pr-4 text-right text-sm font-medium sm:pr-6">
                                <a href="#" class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900">Edit<span class="sr-only">, Lindsay Walton</span></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 py-4 pl-4 pr-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 sm:pl-6">Cayla</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">Windler</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">wanda45@example.net</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 py-4 pl-3 pr-4 text-right text-sm font-medium sm:pr-6">
                                <a href="#" class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900">Edit<span class="sr-only">, Lindsay Walton</span></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 py-4 pl-4 pr-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 sm:pl-6">Demarcus</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">O&#039;Conner</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">klein.brian@example.net</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 py-4 pl-3 pr-4 text-right text-sm font-medium sm:pr-6">
                                <a href="#" class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900">Edit<span class="sr-only">, Lindsay Walton</span></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 py-4 pl-4 pr-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 sm:pl-6">Shaylee</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">Fay</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">hassie50@example.net</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 py-4 pl-3 pr-4 text-right text-sm font-medium sm:pr-6">
                                <a href="#" class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900">Edit<span class="sr-only">, Lindsay Walton</span></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 py-4 pl-4 pr-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 sm:pl-6">Helena</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">Windler</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">kfriesen@example.net</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 py-4 pl-3 pr-4 text-right text-sm font-medium sm:pr-6">
                                <a href="#" class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900">Edit<span class="sr-only">, Lindsay Walton</span></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 py-4 pl-4 pr-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 sm:pl-6">Burdette</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">Kerluke</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">lupe21@example.com</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 py-4 pl-3 pr-4 text-right text-sm font-medium sm:pr-6">
                                <a href="#" class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900">Edit<span class="sr-only">, Lindsay Walton</span></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 py-4 pl-4 pr-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 sm:pl-6">Ludie</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">Ruecker</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">sporer.joanne@example.net</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 py-4 pl-3 pr-4 text-right text-sm font-medium sm:pr-6">
                                <a href="#" class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900">Edit<span class="sr-only">, Lindsay Walton</span></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 py-4 pl-4 pr-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 sm:pl-6">Bret</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">Smith</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">susanna.hermiston@example.org</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 py-4 pl-3 pr-4 text-right text-sm font-medium sm:pr-6">
                                <a href="#" class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900">Edit<span class="sr-only">, Lindsay Walton</span></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 py-4 pl-4 pr-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 sm:pl-6">Dulce</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">Blanda</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">parker.bertram@example.net</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 py-4 pl-3 pr-4 text-right text-sm font-medium sm:pr-6">
                                <a href="#" class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900">Edit<span class="sr-only">, Lindsay Walton</span></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 py-4 pl-4 pr-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 sm:pl-6">Emmet</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">Schowalter</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">julia.sanford@example.com</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 py-4 pl-3 pr-4 text-right text-sm font-medium sm:pr-6">
                                <a href="#" class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900">Edit<span class="sr-only">, Lindsay Walton</span></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 py-4 pl-4 pr-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 sm:pl-6">Devon</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">DuBuque</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">wanda.feest@example.net</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 py-4 pl-3 pr-4 text-right text-sm font-medium sm:pr-6">
                                <a href="#" class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900">Edit<span class="sr-only">, Lindsay Walton</span></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 py-4 pl-4 pr-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 sm:pl-6">Maybell</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">Morissette</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">bailee.ziemann@example.com</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 py-4 pl-3 pr-4 text-right text-sm font-medium sm:pr-6">
                                <a href="#" class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900">Edit<span class="sr-only">, Lindsay Walton</span></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 py-4 pl-4 pr-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 sm:pl-6">Ladarius</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">Kub</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">pfeffer.fritz@example.net</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 py-4 pl-3 pr-4 text-right text-sm font-medium sm:pr-6">
                                <a href="#" class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900">Edit<span class="sr-only">, Lindsay Walton</span></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 py-4 pl-4 pr-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 sm:pl-6">Drake</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">Runte</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">christiansen.hildegard@example.org</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 py-4 pl-3 pr-4 text-right text-sm font-medium sm:pr-6">
                                <a href="#" class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900">Edit<span class="sr-only">, Lindsay Walton</span></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 py-4 pl-4 pr-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 sm:pl-6">Ressie</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">Ledner</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">afadel@example.org</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 py-4 pl-3 pr-4 text-right text-sm font-medium sm:pr-6">
                                <a href="#" class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900">Edit<span class="sr-only">, Lindsay Walton</span></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 py-4 pl-4 pr-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 sm:pl-6">Paolo</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">Wisozk</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">rusty.roob@example.com</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 py-4 pl-3 pr-4 text-right text-sm font-medium sm:pr-6">
                                <a href="#" class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900">Edit<span class="sr-only">, Lindsay Walton</span></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 py-4 pl-4 pr-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 sm:pl-6">Vallie</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">Murazik</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">karolann16@example.com</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 py-4 pl-3 pr-4 text-right text-sm font-medium sm:pr-6">
                                <a href="#" class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900">Edit<span class="sr-only">, Lindsay Walton</span></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 py-4 pl-4 pr-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 sm:pl-6">Alberto</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">Rice</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">kirlin.marcos@example.net</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 py-4 pl-3 pr-4 text-right text-sm font-medium sm:pr-6">
                                <a href="#" class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900">Edit<span class="sr-only">, Lindsay Walton</span></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 py-4 pl-4 pr-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 sm:pl-6">Trystan</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">Shields</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">kassandra.grimes@example.net</td>
                            <td class="whitespace-nowrap bg-indigo-100 py-4 pl-3 pr-4 text-right text-sm font-medium sm:pr-6">
                                <a href="#" class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900">Edit<span class="sr-only">, Lindsay Walton</span></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <!-- More people... -->
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```